# How to display the final paragraph of a text document?

Tags: text-processing

say I have three small paragraphs, word count is or a tad more than 100 how do I only show the final paragraph?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk` paragraph-mode (when `RS` is empty; paragraphs delimited by sequences of empty lines, leading and trailing empty lines ignored):

```
awk -v RS= 'END{print}' < file.txt
```

Note that it prints an empty line if the input file doesn't contain any paragraph (is empty or contains only empty lines). To guard against that, you can change the above to:

```
awk -v RS= 'END{if (NR) print}' < file.txt
```

(`NR` being the number of *records* (in this case *paragraphs*) in the file).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your paragraphs are separated by blank lines, the following command should work (replace the three "test" occurrences by whatever your filename is):

```
tail -n `expr $(wc -l test | cut -f1 -d' ') - \
              $(grep -ERn '^$' test | tail -n1 | grep -o '[0-9]\+')` test
```

I'm pretty sure that there's a much simpler solution, here I'm looking for the last blank line with `grep -ERn '^$' test | tail -n1` and removing everything before with the first `tail`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no trailing empty lines in your input, you could run:

```
sed 'H;/^$/h;$!d;x' infile
```

This overwrites the hold space with the content of each paragraph, deleting the pattern space except when on the last line when it exchanges buffers. Note that you'll get a leading empty line in the output but that's easy to remove... I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

mash of `tac` and `sed`. Assumes blank line separates paragraphs

```
$ cat ip.txt 
some words
in 1st para

some in 2nd one

and few words in last para
as well.
```

If blank line in output is okay:

```
$ tac ip.txt | sed -n '1,/^$/p' | tac

and few words in last para
as well.
```

If not:

```
$ tac ip.txt | sed -n '1,/^$/{/^$/!p}' | tac
and few words in last para
as well.
```

And if there can be white-spaces in the blank line, use `/^\s*$/` instead of `/^$/`

---

with `perl`'s paragraph mode:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if eof' ip.txt 
and few words in last para
as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on *CaptainCap*'s answer, you can do something simpler with `awk`:

```
tail -n$(tac myFile.txt | awk '/^$/{print NR-1; exit}') myFile.txt
```

Assuming paragraphs are separated by empty lines (or containing only blanks).

EDIT: got confused between `tac` and `rev`, you need to use `tac` for it to work indeed.

EDIT: if you're worried about trailing empty lines in your file, here is a way to work around them in `awk`:

```
tail -n $(tac myFile.txt | \
          awk 'BEGIN{i=1} /^$/{if (NR == i) {i++} else {print NR-1; exit}}') \
     myFile.txt
```

Tested it, seems to work as intended!